# Issue in XSLT function to truncate 1000 characters

Tags: xml, parsing, xslt

I am using below statement to truncate a string by 1000 characters.

```
substring('string', 1, 999)
```

But, I am getting 1004 characters for this field.

When I diagnosed, I found that in my string, there are 5 dots for Unordered  list. So, these characters are getting escaped.

So, I used below function to replace these special characters:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(replace(/ps:Position/ps:Job_Requisition_Data/ps:Justification, '.,&#xA;&#xD;&amp;#1;â€™-', '  '), 1, 999)"/>
```

Still, there is no luck and I am getting 1004 characters.

Can you please suggest me about the mistake I am doing?

Comment: Can you put the string which you are trying to truncate ?

Comment: Actually, you should be getting 999 characters. But as amit4497 already wrote, you need to post your input string.

Comment: How do you count the characters? May be a coding issue (UTF-8, ISO)?

Comment: What does the `â€™-` do.